# Error code of 12019 is the response in server environment and not in localhost environment

Tags: javascript, ajax, security

I'm writing a Asynchronous call using AJAX method which passes on a XML string as a post parameter over to a external vendor site which is a .aspx page. In response I receive a redirect URL to which I need to redirect the user.

When I try running the code in my local workspace using the local server it does redirects to the vendor page. But when I do the same from dev environment after getting the code deployed it throws me a http error code 12019 (ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_HANDLE_STATE).

I use IE9 browser to test this application. I dont understand why does it not allow me from enterprise server while it does from the local websphere server.

Comment: First, does your implementation conforms to XHR Cross-Origin security policies ? Are you trying to request an URL which have a different origin than your webpage ?